# PHP Mysql refusing to work with integers

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I am having trouble figuring out how to retrieve data from mysql using php where i have a variable as an integer.
in database time is (int)11

in phpmyadmin my query is and i get the correct results

```
SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE (`sender` = "f3a8ce96-bfb9-410a-81fb-9deffb7305b2" OR `receiver` = "f3a8ce96-bfb9-410a-81fb-9deffb7305b2") AND `time` >= 1437249470
```

in php i have

```
$past = "1437249470";
$user = "f3a8ce96-bfb9-410a-81fb-9deffb7305b2";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE (sender = '".$user."' OR receiver = '".$user."') AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time) >= $past LIMIT 10";
```

in php it gives me random and not relevant results

How do i get this to work correctly in php like it does in phpmyyadmin?

example output
phpymadmin:

```
Quill Littlefeather Josh Piper  $275    07/24/15    Object Buy 7/24/2015 7:57:50 AM
```

php:

```
Quill Littlefeather Josh Piper  $275    04/16/15    Object Buy 4/16/2015 3:41:12 AM
```

Makes no sence the results should be the same in php as it would be in phpmyadmin.

and yes i know this is not pdo style but pdo is a pain and overly complicated.

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME(\`time\`)`, in addition `PDO` is not a pain and overly complicated compared to fixing a site that has been hacked

Comment: Your two queries aren't the same. It's not an apples to apples comparison. What does: `SELECT * FROM \`transactions\` WHERE (\`sender\` = "f3a8ce96-bfb9-410a-81fb-9deffb7305b2" OR \`receiver\` = "f3a8ce96-bfb9-410a-81fb-9deffb7305b2") AND FROM_UNIXTIME(\`time\`) >= 1437249470 LIMIT 10;` return in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue was that i had

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE (sender = '".$user."' OR receiver = '".$user."') AND FROM_UNIXTIME(time) >= $past LIMIT 10";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE (sender = '".$user."' OR receiver = '".$user."') AND time >= '".$past."' LIMIT 10";
```